# Trouble getting my character to follow a curved path

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, bezier-curves

I seem to be having issues getting my character to follow a curved path I've set up. I've been playing around with it and nothing seems to work properly. Whether I parent the bones in Object Mode to the path using Ctrl + P, or adding a Constraint to the bones, my character either just walks on the spot, walks around the path in a diagonal position, or walks but then the animation stops. Even if I adjust the amount of repeated steps, the scale, the amount of frames etc. nothing seems to work. I think the axis are a bit messed up with my rig somewhere.

Can someone please take a look at my file and help me solve this? I'm completely at a loss how to get this working properly. The default frames for my walking animation is 40.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Put the origin of the curve at its beginning vertex (<kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to 3D Cursor*).
- Disable the different *Follow Path* constraints of the character objects (you don’t need them).
- Switch your armature to *Object* mode, give it a *Follow Path* constraint, choose the curve as *Target*, enable the *Follow Curve* option.
- Clear the *Location* of the armature with an <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>.
- Rotate the armature the way it is supposed to be (<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+180).
- Select the curve.
- Open the *Graph Edito*r, display the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>), open the *Modifiers* tab and deactivate the *Generator* (which is automatically created with the *Follow Path* but won't help you here).
- On the *Timeline* go to frame 0.
- Keep the curve selected and go to the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Path Animation*, choose an *Evaluation Time* of 0 and and insert a keyframe.
- On the *Timeline* go to the frame you want, and in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Path Animation*, insert a new keyframe in the *Evaluation Time* with the value you want.
- In the *Graph Editor*, put your mouse over the graph and press <kbd>T</kbd> > *Set Keyframe Interpolation*, and choose *Linear* so that the movement along the curve is linear.

You can speed up the animation of the character along the curve with the *Evaluation Time* value.

You can speed up the walk cycle speed itself in the *NLA Editor* (right properties panel > *Scale* value).

But first, make sure first that no action is loaded in the *Dopesheet* editor, otherwise this action will play over the NLA strip.

Also, note that you can quickly edit the action of a NLA strip, selecting the strip and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>. The pin (on the left of the track) will allow you to see the animation with or without the NLA settings effect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That's pretty much got it. :D However, I can't seem to get my character to continuously walk from start to finish. Even when adjusting the scale and number of repeated steps. He gets to frame 40 and just stops animating. If I put the total frames to 40, he'll animate to the end, but the walking will be far too quick. Again, adjusting the scale and repeat doesn't do much.

Comment: Also, what exactly does that Generator do under Modifiers? And why do keyframes need to be added to the curve itself? Thanks.

Comment: As soon as you create a Follow Path constraint to your object it automatically creates a Generator, but it's much more convenient to control the animation with keyframes and graph curves so most of the time I guess you'll have to delete it.

Comment: about your walk, you need to play with the speed along the path, with the amount and scale of the strip, etc... also you have to avoid any feet gliding, it's a bit hard to fix of course   ;)

Comment: I can't seem to get it. :-\ I keep adjusting the number of frames, scale, repeated steps, but as I say, it either animates from start to finish too fast, or the walk cycle stops at frame 40 every time even if I manage to slow it down. It never reaches the end of the path.

Comment: please share your file again

Comment: I've updated the save file. :)

Comment: You need to play with the second Evalutation Time keyframe, don't put it at 40, but for example at 4, you will see that the movement is much slower and realistic (well, now you'll have to fix the feet gliding I guess). To make it clear, consider the Frames value (above the Evaluation Time) as the amount of segments of your curve, and the Evaluation Time as the segment where you want your object to be at.

Comment: Argh, I'm still not getting this at all. >_< Putting the Evaluation Time to 4 gives me better walking speed, but increasing/decreasing the amount of frames, repitition, scale still isn't helping with getting the character to reach the end before his 40 frames of animation finishes. :-\

Comment: if you want him to finish his walk in only 40 frames you need to accelerate his walk speed, so go in the NLA > right menu (N) > Animations tab > Action Clip > Playback Settings > Scale. If you want the animation to be displayed in its normal speed in the Dopesheet / Action editor mode, unpin the pin icon of the track in the NLA. Also, you'll need to repeat the cycle in the NLA (one is not enough for the whole curve), the Repeat value is below the Scale.

Comment: Unpin the pin icon of the track...? I don't follow. I'm not seeing a pin icon.

Comment: once you select the strip and press Tab  ;)  it gives you access to the animation in the Dopesheet

Comment: Ahh, okay. I had no idea you could do that.

Comment: oh ok I think I've figured out what may happened, actually maybe you were unable to see any change in the speed when you changed the Scale value because the animation was actually loaded in the Dopesheet, so it was playing the selected Dopesheet action and not the NLA strip, so just close the action in the Dopesheet (X) and then in the NLA make the Scale and Repeat changes you want

Comment: Ahhh, that makes it easier to adjust correctly. Excellent. :D I never would have figured that out... Thank you so much. :)

Comment: What exactly does pinning and unpinning do?

Comment: show the animation transformed or not by the NLA settings